# Java - Search ArrayList in custom service package, call to UI, keep main clean

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I am currently learning Java 9, been at it for a month now and the moment has come when I am utterly stuck. Bear with me on this one, I haven't found an answer on related questions or at least I'm stupid enough to not have seen the answer to my question.

I am developing a drug shop/pharmacy console application which lets me add a drug by id, name, quantity, price/unit and a functionality that lets me search for a string with .contains(), transfers the found drugs to a new ArrayList and then outputs them to the user.

Now the problem is this: when I search for a drug it's outputting only the first one in the ArrayList even though the string is present in multiple drug names.
It would surely help if I knew how to iGnOrE cAsE but if I search for 'Amo' it outputs 'Amoxicillin' just fine even though it's on the nth position.

Here's the code:
The domain - Constructor, getters, setters, for ID, name, quantity, price/unit
I haven't included the whole Domain because WallOfUnnecessaryCode. I just want you to know it's there.

```
package DrugDomain;
public class Drug {
    private int drugID;
    private String drugName;
    private int drugQuantity;
    private float drugPrice;

    /**
     * Constructor for Drug object
     * @param drugName     name
     * @param drugQuantity quantity
     * @param drugPrice    price in $$$
     */
    public Drug(int drugID, String drugName, int drugQuantity, float drugPrice) {
        this.drugID = drugID;
        this.drugName = drugName;
        this.drugQuantity = drugQuantity;
        this.drugPrice = drugPrice;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for ID
     * @return ID
     */
    public int getDrugID() {
        return drugID;
    }
```

The Repository:

```
package DrugRepository;
import DrugDomain.Drug;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DrugRepo {

    private List<Drug> drugList = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Finds a drug by IDs
     * @param theID searched ID
     * @return the drug or null if not present
     */
    public Drug findID(int theID) {
        for (Drug drug : this.drugList) {
            if (drug.getDrugID() == theID) {
                return drug;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new drug
     * @param aDrug drug that will be added to list
     * @return added drug or null if you try to add an ID duplicate
     */
    public Drug add(Drug aDrug) {
        Drug ifExists = this.findID(aDrug.getDrugID());
        if (ifExists == null) {
            this.drugList.add(aDrug);
            return aDrug;
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for drug list
     * @return list with all drugs
     */
    public List<Drug> getAll() {
        return this.drugList;
    }


}
```

The Service: here I tried to implement the search function

```
package DrugService;
import DrugDomain.Drug;
import DrugRepository.DrugRepo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ShopService {
    private DrugRepo drugListService;

    public ShopService(DrugRepo drugListS) {
        this.drugListService = drugListS;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a new drug
     *
     * @param drID     drug ID
     * @param name     drug name
     * @param quantity drug quantity
     * @param price    drug price
     */
    public void addDrug(int drID, String name, int quantity, float price) {
        Drug newDrug = new Drug(drID, name, quantity, price);
        this.drugListService.add(newDrug);
    }

    /**
     * Searching for a drug by string
     * @param query String asked for
     * @return A list of drugs that .contains the string inputted
     */
    public List<Drug> getSearchResult(String query) {
        List<Drug> allDrugs = this.getAll();
        List<Drug> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Drug d : allDrugs) {
            if (d.getDrugName().contains(query)) {
                result.add(d);
            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<Drug> getAll() {
        return this.drugListService.getAll();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(obj);
    }
}
```

The User Interface:

```
package UI;
import DrugDomain.Drug;
import DrugService.ShopService;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StoreFrontUI {

    private Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    private ShopService drugService;

    public StoreFrontUI(ShopService drugServiceConsole) {
        this.drugService = drugServiceConsole;
    }

    private void listAllDrugs() {
        for (Drug drug : this.drugService.getAll()) {
            System.out.println(drug);
        }
    }

    private void addADrug() {
        System.out.print("Enter drug ID: ");
        int drugID = this.userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter drug name:");
        String drugName = this.userInput.next();
        System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
        int drugQuant = this.userInput.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter price/unit: ");
        float drugPrice = this.userInput.nextFloat();

        this.drugService.addDrug(drugID, drugName, drugQuant, drugPrice);
    }

    private void searchDrug() {
        System.out.print("Search: ");
        String search = userInput.next();
        System.out.println(this.drugService.getSearchResult(search));

    }


    private void storeFrontMenu() {
        System.out.println("1. Add drug to stock.");
        System.out.println("2. Search for drug.");
        System.out.println("3. Sort drugs.");
        System.out.println("4. Add to shopping cart.");
        System.out.println("5. Checkout.");
        System.out.println("6. Most expensive product in cart.");
        System.out.println("s. Show all drugs.");
        System.out.println("x. Exit");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("ENTER OPTION: ");
    }

    public void openShopMenu() {

        while (true) {
            this.storeFrontMenu();

            String option = userInput.next();
            if (option.equals("1")) {
                this.addADrug();
            } else if (option.equals("2")) {
                this.searchDrug();
            } else if (option.equals("3")) {
                // TODO: 10/30/2017
            } else if (option.equals("4")) {
                // TODO: 10/30/2017
            } else if (option.equals("5")) {
                // TODO: 10/30/2017
            } else if (option.equals("6")) {
                // TODO: 10/30/2017
            } else if (option.equals("s")) {
                this.listAllDrugs();
            } else if (option.equals("x")) {
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Command! Try Again!");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

Main:

```
package com.daedalus;
import DrugRepository.DrugRepo;
import DrugService.ShopService;
import UI.StoreFrontUI;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrugRepo drugRepo = new DrugRepo();
        ShopService drugService = new ShopService(drugRepo);
      //drugService.addDrug(ID, name, quantity, price/unit);
        drugService.addDrug(1,"Paracetamol", 300, 3.95f);
        drugService.addDrug(2,"Aspirin", 247, 2.95f);
        drugService.addDrug(3,"Amoxicillin", 150, 12.45f);
        drugService.addDrug(4,"Fentanol", 50, 15.45f);
        drugService.addDrug(5,"Oxicontin", 300, 17.45f);
        drugService.addDrug(6,"Robotine", 110, 11.45f);

        StoreFrontUI console = new StoreFrontUI(drugService);

        console.openShopMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `return result;` in the search method is obviously misplaced, it breaks the loop

Comment: For the "ignore case" part, how about transforming both the drug name and the query before the `contains`?

Comment: (voting to close as typo)

Comment: So I edited the code and I return the result after the for loop. I search for 'a' and it gives me ID1 and 4, Paracetampl and Fentanol. I've done this before and missed the part where it can't give me ID2 Aspirin or ID3 Amoxicillin. Obviously it's because it doesn't ignore case... I'm gonna experiment a bit with what you said and I'll come back with some result. Thanks!

Comment: Don't fix the code in the question. Delete the question if it's now fixed, or post the solution as an answer.

Comment: Undid my edit, sorry I'm a n00b and idk how you guys like things here. But i solved my stuff:

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<Drug> getSearchResult(String query) {
    List<Drug> allDrugs = this.getAll();
    List<Drug> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Drug d : allDrugs) {
        query = query.toLowerCase();
        if (d.getDrugName().toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
            result.add(d);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Solution for searching in an array whilst ignoring case. Thx for the tips guys!